# Integral representation of Bessel function of the first kind from generating function

Tags: integration, summation, substitution, bessel-functions

I need to prove
$$
\operatorname{J}_{n\,}\left(x\right) =
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
{\rm e}^{-{\rm i}x\sin\left(\theta + in\theta\right)}
\hspace{5mm}{\rm d}\theta
$$
using something I already proved previously:

$$
{\rm e}^{x\left(t - 1/t\right)/2}\,\,\, =
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}
\operatorname{J}_{n}\left(x\right)\,t^{n}
$$

I can see that substituting
$$
t = {\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta}
$$
will get me $99\,\%$ of the way there, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the infinite sum to have the integral, nor why the sign of the second term in the exponential is positive.

Thanks !.

Comment: This may be of [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4376450/121671)

Comment: You can read the [MSE Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is $\tt MathJax$ for MSE. Enjoy it !!!.

Comment: What is the integral of $e^{in\theta}$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a sign error in the integral representaiton of the first-kind Bessel function of order $n$ as stated in the OP.

The correct representation of the Bessel function is

$$J_{n}(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i\color{red}{n}\theta-ix\sin(\theta)}\,d\theta$$

where the red-colored $n$ shows the location where the OP had $-n$ instead.

---

Now, letting $t=e^{-i\theta}$ in the expression for the generating function reveals

$$e^{x(t-1/t)/2}=e^{-ix\sin(\theta)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n(x)e^{-in\theta}$$

Expoiting the orthogonality of $e^{in\theta}$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ix\sin(\theta)}e^{in\theta}&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty J_{m}(x)e^{-im\theta}e^{in\theta}\,d\theta\\\\
&\frac1{2\pi}\left(2\pi \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty J_{m}(x)\delta_{m,n}\right)\\\\
&=J_n(x)
\end{align}$$

as expected!